# QT screen crashes after executing OpenCV function 'VideoWriter.open'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm using the QTCreator IDE to create my screens, in addition to that, I'm using the OpenCV library to capture frames from my webcam and display them in the QLabel of the QT screen. When clicking the record button, my screen crashes. What could be causing this? What can I do so that my code is able to record camera frames without breaking the code?

When debugging the code, the following message appears when I execute line 84 'videoWriter.open("/home/guardiantech/Desktop/video.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P ', 'G'), fps, cv::Size(frame_width, frame_height));' from my code:

"The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name:

SIGSEGV

Signal meaning:

Segmentation fault"

and the error message:

"16:44:43: Starting /home/guardiantech/Desktop/build-projeto_c-Desktop_Qt_6_4_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/projeto_c...
[ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1100) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
16:44:46: /home/guardiantech/Desktop/build-projeto_c-Desktop_Qt_6_4_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/projeto_c crashed."

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    telaprincipal.cpp

HEADERS += \
    telaprincipal.h

FORMS += \
    telaprincipal.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

.h file:

```
#ifndef TELAPRINCIPAL_H
#define TELAPRINCIPAL_H
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class TelaPrincipal; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class TelaPrincipal : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TelaPrincipal(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~TelaPrincipal();

private:
    Ui::TelaPrincipal *ui;
    QLabel *camera;
    cv::VideoCapture *videoCapture;
    cv::Mat frame;
    bool gravando = false;
    cv::VideoWriter videoWriter;

public slots:
    void atualizaFrame();
private slots:
    void on_botao_foto_clicked();
    void on_botao_gravar_clicked();
};
#endif // TELAPRINCIPAL_H
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include "telaprincipal.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TelaPrincipal w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

telaprincipal.cpp file:

```
#include "telaprincipal.h"
#include "ui_telaprincipal.h"

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include <QTimer>

TelaPrincipal::TelaPrincipal(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::TelaPrincipal)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    camera = ui->frame;

    videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture(0);
    //std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;

    QTimer *cameraTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(cameraTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &TelaPrincipal::atualizaFrame);
    cameraTimer->start(0);
}

TelaPrincipal::~TelaPrincipal()
{
    delete videoCapture;
    delete ui;
}

void TelaPrincipal::atualizaFrame()
{
    if(videoCapture->isOpened())
    {
        *videoCapture >> frame;

        if(!frame.empty())
        {
            QImage img(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_BGR888);

            camera->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        }

        if(gravando)
        {
            videoWriter.write(frame);
        }
    }
}


void TelaPrincipal::on_botao_gravar_clicked()
{
    if(!gravando)
    {

        if (!videoCapture->isOpened()) {
            std::cerr << "Erro: a câmera não foi inicializada corretamente." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        int frame_largura = videoCapture->get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        int frame_altura = videoCapture->get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

        double fps = videoCapture->get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);

        videoWriter.open("/path/to/my/file/video.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, cv::Size(frame_largura, frame_altura)); //the aplication crashes on this line

        if (!videoWriter.isOpened()) {
            std::cerr << "Erro ao abrir o arquivo de vídeo para gravação." << std::endl;
        }

        gravando = true;
        ui->botoes->setPixmap(QPixmap("/path/to/my/img/backUI-2.png"));

    } else
    {
        gravando = false;
        ui->botoes->setPixmap(QPixmap("/path/to/my/img/backUI.png"));

        videoWriter.release();
    }
}
```

Notes:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Release:    22.04

Codename:   jammy

Opencv4

c++17

QT6

Comment: Did you intend to use gstreamer as an api of opencv's video i/o module? If you did, I think you should use the gstreamer's pipeline string, not the file path, as a first argument of ```VideoWriter::open```.